# Using procedures module Prolog

Tags: stored-procedures, module, prolog, swi-prolog

I defined a prolog `increment` procedure inside a module in a `procs1.pl` file.

How can I import the procedures defined within the module and use them in such a way as not to import them into the default `user` form but in the form in which I defined the procedure that I invoked.

Since I have defined several prolog procedure files, I would like each file to be loaded into a separate module.

If, for example, I have two files containing certain procedures `procs1.pl` and `procs2.pl`, and in both files the `increment` procedure is present, I would like to specify the procedure of which module to use.

`procs1.pl`

`:- module('procs1',[increment/2]).
increment(X,C) :- C is X+1.`

Comment: `:- use_module(procs1, []).` ensures that the module is loaded, same for `procs2`. You now can only refer to `increment/2` as `procs1:increment(1,X)`.

Comment: Downside: `meta_predicate` declarations are effectively ignored that way, that is, you have to do qualification explicitly for meta-arguments

Comment: but before using `use_module`, should I `consult` by entering the path to the procs1 file?

Comment: Consider to use the `library` mechanism for that.

Comment: I proved entering `use_module` but it gives me an error: `source_sink does not exist`. surely before doing `procs1: increment(2,X)` I have to run the `procs1: consult(path)` but I don't know if it inserts everything in the `user` module or in `procs1`

Comment: No consult is necessary. Start with all files in the same directory.

Comment: in this way it works: `use_module('C://Users/user/procs.pl'), procs:increment(1,X). `If I do this, does the saving occur in the `user`(default) module or in the `procs` module? Sorry for the questions

Comment: You are hard coding paths, that's not the best. But indeed it works. The module in your example is in `procs`.